# How do I locate and replace text with a common element using regex?

Tags: php, regex

I'm pretty lousy at regex, and need help with the following scenario. I need to locate and replace text that has a common structure, but one aspect will be different:

```
here is a string (with 3 values)
here is another string (with 5 values)
```

In the above examples, I need to locate and then replace the value in parenthesis. I can't search by parens alone, as the string may contain other parens. But the value in the parens that needs to be replaced is consistently constructed: `(with # values)` -- the only difference will be the number.

So ideally the regex returns `(with 3 values)` and `(with 5 values)` so I can use a simple `str_replace` to change the text.

This is regex in a PHP script.

Comment: Could you give an example of a string (I mean a real example, with values) ?

Comment: I think the string provided is literal @Gawil

Comment: The examples provided are identical in structure to the actual values.

Comment: @lcdservices: Which values? Numbers? Spaces? Alphanumerics? Please be more precise.

Comment: Can the number be any length or only one digit? And if they can be any length, can they begin with 0? Any other restrictions? Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: @lcdservices Oh ok I didn't understand that `with # values` was the real construction of the parenthesis ^^ The regex you need seems pretty simple then : `\(with\s+\d+\s+values\)`

Comment: @Jan - see my statement "So ideally..." for what I would like returned -- the entire value in parens where the string match begins with "(with" and ends with "values)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this regex :
`\(with\s+\d+\s+values\)`
Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/PJoYoJ/1)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work for you:

```
/\(with (\d+) values\)/g
```

This matches strings of the specified format and gives the value in a capture group so it may be used in the replace. The `g` flag at the end is only needed if you have multiple of these in one string.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/SqjWGd/1)

If, however, there can only be one digit, then the following will work:

```
/\(with (\d) values\)/g
```

Or, if the number can only be a digit greater than 1, for example, then the following:

```
/\(with ([2-9]) values\)/g
```

Comment: He **did** specify `PHP`, didn't he?

Comment: @Jan yes, but he only asked for the regex, not the PHP code itself. I inferred from the question that he has enough PHP knowledge to incorporate the regex himself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe

```
$str ="here is another string (with 5 values)";

preg_match_all("/\(with (\d+) values\)/", $str, $out );

print_r( $out );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (with 5 values)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

)
```

[Here at ideone](http://ideone.com/PyDe5Y)...

It uses the regex

```
\(with (\d+) values\)
```

that matches the literal opening parentheses followed by the string *with # values*, capturing the actual number `#`, and finally the closing parentheses.

It returns the complete match (the parenthesized string) in the first dimension and the **actual number** in the second.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are looking for exactly three or five items within parentheses (comma separated).
This could be accomplished by

```
\(                        # "(" literally
    (?:[^,()]+,){2}       # not , or ( or ) exactly two times
    (?:(?:[^,()]+,){2})?  # repeated
    [^,()]+               # without the comma in the end
\)                        # the closing parenthesis
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/2znf8d/2/).

---

If you're really looking only for two variant of strings, you could very easily do

```
\(with (?:3|5) values\)
```

In general

```
\(with \d+ values\)
```

as proposed by @SchoolBoy.

Comment: No, OP is looking for the literal string `"(with # values)"`

Comment: @SchoolBoy: Really? This is pretty simple, isn't it?

Comment: I also don't think he means only 3 or 5 lol. But i'd let this stay here just in case.

Comment: @SchoolBoy: Updated.